# NSGA-II implementation

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I have studied about Non dominating sorting algorithtm (NSGA-II).
I want to use this multi objective optimization algorithm.
could anybody help me by addressing any free implementation of NSGA-II in java or matlab.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I had a brief look at jMetal, but the quality of the code seems lacking (to a Java software engineer) compared to the solid [Watchmaker](http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/) which I came across soon after. Watchmaker supports a very generic approach to building evolutionary algorithms by plugging components together, so I'd be interested to know if NSGA-II has been or can be implemented within it? I suppose I'll find out myself soon enough.

Answer (score 3):

[MOEA Framework](http://moeaframework.org/) is a a free and open source Java framework for Multiobjective Optimization. It has the largest collection of MOEAs of any library, including NSGA-I, NSGA-II, and NSGA-III.

I personally used it to implement and solve a Multi Objective Problem (MOP) for my Master's thesis and found it far superior to [PyGMO](http://esa.github.io/pygmo/) (for python) and [jMetal](http://jmetal.sourceforge.net/) (in Java).

The following code demonstrates how to use the MOEA Framework API to run NSGA-II to solve the ZDT1 multiobjective problem:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.moeaframework.Executor;
import org.moeaframework.core.NondominatedPopulation;
import org.moeaframework.core.Solution;

public class NSGAIIExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // configure and run this experiment
        NondominatedPopulation result = new Executor()
                .withProblem("ZDT1")
                .withAlgorithm("NSGAII")
                .withMaxEvaluations(1000)
                .distributeOnAllCores()
                .run();

        List<NondominatedPopulation> multiRuns = new Executor()
                .withProblem("ZDT1")
                .withAlgorithm("NSGAII")
                .withMaxEvaluations(1000)
                .distributeOnAllCores()
                .runSeeds(3);

        System.out.format("Obj1  Obj2%n");
        for (Solution solution : result) {
            System.out.format("%.5f\t%.5f%n", solution.getObjective(0),
                    solution.getObjective(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Austin would you mind expanding a little on how MOEA is superior to jMetal? I'm about to start using one of the two for a project and am a little hesitant to use MOEA since it doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore, whereas jMetal is.

Comment: @qwertz MOEA Framework actually used the jMetal implementations for many of their algorithms. So, jMetal is effectively a subcomponent of MOEA Framework.

Answer (score 2):

jMetal is the Java framework of MOEA, which NSGA-II is included in.  The website is [here](http://jmetal.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: "jMetal is *the* Java framework of MOEA […]" sounds like it is some sort of official reference implementation, which is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you want from Matlab

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10429-nsga-ii-a-multi-objective-optimization-algorithm

And here's one for Java:

http://ia-2008.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/TrabajoPracticoFinal/Implementacion/NSGA/src/jmetal/metaheuristics/nsgaII/NSGAII.java

Answer (score 0):

Since it hasn't been mentioned so far: [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/)

> Jenetics is an advanced Genetic Algorithm, Evolutionary Algorithm and Genetic Programming library, respectively, written in modern day Java.

As of version 4.1.0 the `jenetics.ext` module offers classes for multi-objective problems. It also offers a [`NSGA2Selector`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics.ext/4.3/io/jenetics/ext/moea/NSGA2Selector.html), but (taken from the [manual v4.3.0](http://jenetics.io/manual/manual-4.3.0.pdf), p. 92):

> Since the MOO classes are an extensions to the existing evolution Engine, the implementation doesn't exactly follow an established algorithm, like NSGA2 or SPEA2. The results and performance, described in the relevant papers, are therefore not directly comparable.

Nonetheless, this might reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Have quickly read this thread and I haven't seen a mention of platEMO. Which is a matlab based optimisation platform that I have used a lot recently. The documentation and installation information can be found at:

**https://github.com/BIMK/PlatEMO**

It has a large amount of problems and algorithms (including NSGA-II) as standard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).